# Use jq to remove key/value pairs based on other file

Tags: json, key, jq, intersect

I have 2 json files containing translations for my app:

en-US.json:

```json
{
    "car": "car",
    "bike": "bike",
    "tree": "tree",
}
```

nl-NL.json:

```json
{
    "car": "auto",
    "bike": "fiets",
    "tree": "boom",
    "house": "huis"
}
```

As you can see, I have removed the `house` from the en-US.json file (among many others). How could I remove the same `house` entry from my nl-NL.json file with jq? I basically want to get the intersection of both files, based on key.

I've been playing with `jq 'keys'` to get all keys, but that does not work. I think it should be found in the direction of `jq --slurpfile en en-US.json 'del($en)' nl-NL.json` but that totally does not work :(  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the `nl-NL.json` file to the keys present in `en-US.json`, you could read in the latter as reference, then [`select`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select%28boolean_expression%29) from the input turned into entries those keys that are present in the reference file. [`in`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#in) checks "whether or not the input key is in the given object".

```bash
jq --argfile ref en-US.json 'with_entries(select(.key | in($ref)))' nl-NL.json
```

```json
{
  "car": "auto",
  "bike": "fiets",
  "tree": "boom"
}
```

Comment: Note: If you prefer using `--slurpfile` over `--argfile`, also change `$ref` to `$ref[]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes total sense!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like this:

```
$ jq 'del(.[(keys - (input | keys))[]])' nl-NL.json en-US.json
{
  "car": "auto",
  "bike": "fiets",
  "tree": "boom"
}
```